# Операция Transactional в Spring

Tags: java, spring

У меня есть такой вот метод:

```
@Transactional
public void withdrawMoney(Withdrawal withdrawal) {

    // Если пользователь пытается снять отрицальную или нулевую сумму
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (withdrawal.getValue() >= 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong withdrawal value!");
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Создаем ссылки на персистентные объекты
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Account account;
    Currency currency;
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // К нам приходит не персистентный объект, поэтому вытаскиваем нужные объекты из базы
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    try {
        account = accountRepository.findOne(withdrawal.getAccount().getUuid());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong account uuid");
    }

    try {
        currency = currencyRepository.findOne(withdrawal.getCurrency().getId());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong currency id");
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // Если валюта на счете и валюта снятия не совпадают, то выкидываем исключение
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    if (!account.getCurrency().equals(currency.getName())) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Wrong currency!");
    }
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Вычитаем нужную сумму и сохраняем изменения в объекте
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    account.setValue(account.getValue() - withdrawal.getValue());
    accountRepository.save(account);
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Кладем персистентные объекты в withdrawal
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    withdrawal.setAccount(account);
    withdrawal.setCurrency(currency);
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // Сохраняем операцию снятия денег в базе
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    withdrawalRepository.save(withdrawal);
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

И две проблемы с ним. Первое, мне кажется, что я сильно перемудрил и все можно сделать гораздо проще. И второе - он не работает. Говорит, что все ок, но операция не выполняется. Как правильно воспользоваться аннтация `Transactional` в данном случае ?

Comment: Во-первых, чертовски плохая практика перехватывать исключения типа `Exception`. Во-вторых, чертовски плохая практика выбрасывать исключения типа `RuntimeException`. В-третьих, оператор `>=` означает "больше или равно", а значит будет срабатывать на положительные и нулевые суммы.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а в остальном ?